# How to apply a rolling window with linear regression and multiple variables in R( or python)?

Tags: python, r, regression, rolling-computation, ln

I have date over 708 days. There are 6 products columns with sell numbers in the row.
There are also 13 variables. Most of them are weather date like sun hours or temperature, others are binary (no event=`0`, event=`1`).

The goal is to predict the sell numbers of a product.

The data in the picture is generalized.

[image: r dataframe (generalized)]

What I want to do is a rolling window.
So that I can take 77days to predict the following week (predict day 78 to 84 with 1:77) and then so on (take 8:84 to predict 85:93).
And also I want to compare the combined predictions (78:708) with the actual date.

I didn't find a way to apply a rolling ln function in R which worked.

My python skills are very basic, but a solution in python would also be appreciated.

Model:

model_A<-lm(formula=Produkt_A~weekday+Variable_1+Variable_2+Variable_3+Variable_4+Variable_5+Variable_6+Variable_7+Variable_8+Variable_9+Variable_10+Variable_11+Variable_12+Variable_13,data=df)

First 100 data points:

```r
data <- structure(list(weekday = c(7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 1), Produkt_A = c(204, 187, 189, 203, 217, 211, 222, 
194, 219, 240, 161, 202, 193, 236, 164, 204, 170, 190, 213, 235, 
199, 195, 182, 184, 189, 209, 188, 176, 209, 192, 203, 201, 209, 
256, 216, 198, 209, 169, 192, 173, 170, 201, 170, 186, 166, 200, 
206, 192, 153, 171, 170, 190, 216, 208, 202, 188, 179, 177, 149, 
192, 179, 223, 198, 192, 184, 154, 172, 186, 215, 207, 179, 141, 
167, 181, 182, 181, 202, 168, 216, 197, 211, 191, 210, 200, 171, 
196, 214, 200, 206, 203, 188, 141, 127, 181, 195, 233, 191, 227, 
186, 134), Prdukt_B = c(213, 237, 219, 228, 198, 247, 246, 230, 
229, 192, 236, 182, 205, 202, 167, 206, 195, 179, 209, 211, 232, 
192, 191, 174, 182, 232, 229, 207, 212, 236, 237, 195, 241, 286, 
247, 229, 230, 255, 211, 247, 288, 226, 226, 184, 192, 200, 258, 
238, 270, 224, 194, 197, 228, 244, 230, 241, 215, 218, 218, 196, 
275, 246, 247, 215, 250, 207, 243, 253, 264, 221, 185, 216, 211, 
218, 218, 267, 261, 212, 242, 246, 254, 269, 308, 278, 234, 230, 
259, 225, 232, 257, 209, 193, 192, 193, 240, 229, 220, 242, 210, 
159), Produkt_C = c(18, 27, 37, 21, 27, 20, 35, 15, 27, 20, 23, 
22, 20, 19, 20, 21, 23, 15, 14, 27, 21, 14, 22, 28, 23, 22, 34, 
27, 20, 20, 22, 33, 40, 35, 42, 44, 38, 31, 37, 32, 37, 30, 24, 
20, 28, 29, 26, 36, 29, 24, 15, 31, 22, 31, 39, 35, 39, 35, 31, 
30, 34, 51, 31, 30, 33, 19, 26, 39, 32, 51, 28, 19, 33, 32, 26, 
33, 41, 48, 33, 29, 42, 33, 60, 51, 49, 30, 38, 35, 24, 30, 31, 
19, 16, 26, 33, 24, 38, 32, 35, 24), Produkt_D = c(17, 16, 9, 
23, 27, 25, 4, 8, 14, 19, 26, 23, 28, 7, 17, 17, 18, 22, 25, 
27, 20, 25, 33, 23, 27, 17, 30, 5, 11, 26, 16, 32, 22, 19, 14, 
11, 10, 7, 14, 28, 16, 22, 14, 10, 21, 26, 31, 20, 13, 7, 17, 
20, 17, 29, 26, 8, 4, 18, 12, 14, 14, 15, 12, 10, 7, 25, 26, 
25, 17, 13, 27, 8, 14, 20, 18, 19, 15, 14, 21, 30, 11, 37, 18, 
26, 22, 27, 16, 27, 20, 29, 16, 7, 19, 15, 15, 16, 6, 8, 10, 
9), Produkt_E = c(24, 14, 18, 20, 19, 46, 32, 30, 5, 6, 18, 14, 
26, 17, 37, 25, 27, 9, 16, 39, 21, 14, 15, 7, 14, 17, 24, 20, 
33, 18, 14, 24, 21, 20, 19, 16, 12, 12, 15, 15, 25, 14, 31, 18, 
19, 16, 17, 25, 19, 15, 15, 21, 20, 21, 17, 16, 29, 10, 13, 11, 
16, 15, 24, 20, 25, 12, 15, 17, 30, 24, 24, 21, 14, 18, 21, 25, 
17, 27, 20, 20, 26, 17, 18, 23, 14, 27, 19, 22, 24, 23, 22, 22, 
3, 18, 11, 16, 22, 19, 14, 11), Produkt_F = c(35, 19, 30, 32, 
26, 28, 42, 39, 44, 45, 37, 37, 36, 35, 25, 40, 24, 24, 25, 36, 
31, 26, 22, 27, 21, 21, 34, 49, 41, 33, 38, 33, 34, 40, 68, 80, 
53, 32, 43, 49, 31, 52, 55, 31, 29, 29, 37, 37, 47, 44, 35, 32, 
41, 37, 42, 57, 60, 57, 45, 54, 71, 60, 59, 48, 44, 37, 36, 48, 
47, 64, 53, 40, 45, 49, 24, 46, 88, 54, 49, 38, 65, 60, 69, 72, 
73, 51, 59, 62, 34, 36, 59, 43, 32, 85, 101, 85, 69, 100, 65, 
54), day_number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100), Variable_1 = c(20.2525, 11.7558333333333, 
10.5270833333333, 13.0058333333333, 16.815, 17.56, 13.7058333333333, 
15.96625, 10.5575, 10.295, 13.15125, 13.15, 16.3366666666667, 
18.3704166666667, 16.15875, 14.8670833333333, 16.77875, 16.2008333333333, 
17.5420833333333, 18.44125, 18.3858333333333, 17.1179166666667, 
15.32375, 16.7, 16.3304166666667, 15.5291666666667, 14.015, 13.5420833333333, 
11.9104166666667, 9.43166666666667, 10.9129166666667, 11.8391666666667, 
12.66875, 11.4791666666667, 8.28375, 5.5125, 7.62375, 6.32958333333333, 
8.79041666666667, 10.0675, 10.2854166666667, 9.14708333333333, 
10.8925, 10.9716666666667, 12.175, 12.3229166666667, 11.63, 11.9608333333333, 
11.3966666666667, 13.1179166666667, 10.9333333333333, 11.9541666666667, 
9.16208333333333, 7.23791666666667, 5.10625, 4.1225, 1.80666666666667, 
0.783333333333333, 2.23958333333333, 3.39208333333333, 4.68625, 
5.58291666666667, 7.42, 6.32166666666667, 5.3175, 4.87583333333333, 
5.68708333333333, 7.99666666666667, 7.2825, 7.60416666666667, 
10.75625, 13.2133333333333, 9.9975, 9.67416666666667, 10.5054166666667, 
11.0079166666667, 7.30416666666667, 8.43, 5.37666666666667, 3.07583333333333, 
1.40791666666667, 0.157916666666667, -0.474166666666667, -0.190833333333333, 
3.74333333333333, 4.21875, 2.1925, 4.93083333333333, 6.36416666666667, 
9.21291666666667, 11.2970833333333, 11.095, 7.30041666666667, 
1.94958333333333, 1.66875, 3.9075, 3.83333333333333, 1.32208333333333, 
3.6825, 5.095), Variable_2 = c(27.08, 15.85, 16.71, 20.69, 23.88, 
23.4, 20.01, 23.33, 14.19, 15.34, 17.88, 20.29, 23.75, 25.15, 
19.86, 20.59, 22.79, 24.04, 23.57, 25.6, 24.86, 23.67, 22.81, 
23.11, 21.98, 23.14, 19.35, 18.98, 18.11, 16.25, 17.26, 16.42, 
18.41, 15.73, 11.22, 6.93, 14.21, 10.35, 16.43, 14.73, 14.3, 
15.34, 17.19, 17.52, 18.35, 16.66, 14.73, 16.79, 17.14, 18.36, 
20.95, 15.54, 15.1, 13.15, 10.5, 9.28, 5.6, 6.33, 7.84, 7.94, 
10.86, 10.08, 12.01, 10.34, 6.98, 6.39, 10.29, 13.49, 9.03, 10.56, 
13.51, 15.42, 11.35, 13.67, 12.94, 13.46, 9.06, 10.79, 6.98, 
5.16, 5.71, 3.58, 2.21, 2.51, 7.77, 7.73, 7.19, 7.99, 9.9, 12.04, 
12.67, 13.21, 12.13, 5.1, 5.73, 8.7, 6.81, 3.79, 5.94, 6.84), 
    Variable_3 = c(16.3108333333333, 8.77083333333333, 5.61916666666667, 
    10.2091666666667, 15.34625, 15.6825, 10.9925, 13.9241666666667, 
    6.25583333333333, 6.505, 11.4929166666667, 11.6275, 14.0754166666667, 
    16.5591666666667, 14.9191666666667, 14.0804166666667, 15.9579166666667, 
    13.21, 15.5595833333333, 16.3566666666667, 16.6279166666667, 
    14.2116666666667, 11.51625, 14.625, 14.7758333333333, 14.3008333333333, 
    13.3770833333333, 12.6420833333333, 9.81083333333333, 6.84875, 
    7.50125, 8.26791666666667, 11.1266666666667, 9.33958333333333, 
    5.27416666666667, 0.43625, 4.05916666666667, 0.0675, 4.48416666666667, 
    7.59791666666667, 7.93416666666667, 7.35416666666667, 8.72625, 
    7.64791666666667, 9.56041666666667, 10.08, 9.62041666666667, 
    9.22375, 7.78833333333333, 9.89583333333333, 8.34083333333333, 
    9.55833333333333, 5.55958333333333, 2.96541666666667, 0.897916666666667, 
    -0.807916666666667, -1.76875, -3.45458333333333, -2.23583333333333, 
    -0.18875, 0.573333333333333, 0.973333333333333, 4.225, 2.7525, 
    1.99083333333333, 1.50666666666667, 1.10333333333333, 2.66291666666667, 
    4.52166666666667, 4.9075, 6.25583333333333, 8.1975, 5.69625, 
    5.81625, 8.01458333333333, 6.28416666666667, -0.420833333333333, 
    -0.555416666666667, -0.485416666666667, -0.599583333333333, 
    -2.83291666666667, -4.32, -4.20708333333333, -5.2775, -1.79333333333333, 
    0.420416666666667, -3.52, 0.6125, 1.63625, 2.69125, 5.0475, 
    6.22791666666667, 2.54708333333333, -0.890833333333333, -2.08666666666667, 
    -0.840416666666667, -0.16, -2.14041666666667, -0.218333333333333, 
    2.30125), Variable_4 = c(22.49, 13.49, 10.19, 19.43, 23.17, 
    21.56, 15.64, 21.98, 10.96, 10.5, 16.38, 19.85, 23.08, 24.11, 
    18.98, 20.14, 22.88, 21.46, 21.14, 23.35, 23.62, 21.86, 18.47, 
    21.73, 21.8, 20.06, 19.04, 18.4, 16.13, 14.39, 12.82, 12.23, 
    15.88, 12.21, 7.94, 3.21, 9.03, 3.2, 13.8, 13.07, 11.59, 
    13.75, 16.78, 15.84, 17.63, 14.68, 12.68, 14.96, 14.67, 15.55, 
    21.4, 12.78, 11.87, 9.75, 8.01, 5.49, 2.09, 1.15, 3.77, 4.97, 
    7.88, 5.81, 9.09, 7.94, 3.42, 3.71, 6.81, 8.46, 8.17, 8.58, 
    9.64, 10.1, 7.22, 9.16, 11.14, 10.32, 0.76, 1.58, 0.99, 0.75, 
    0.38, -2.42, -2.44, -3.35, 3.05, 2.56, 0.86, 4.86, 4.04, 
    6.82, 6.83, 8.78, 5.55, 1.45, 2.79, 5.07, 2.44, 0.54, 3.49, 
    3.75), Variable_5 = c(16.3108333333333, 8.77083333333333, 
    5.61916666666667, 10.2091666666667, 15.34625, 15.6825, 10.9925, 
    13.9241666666667, 6.25583333333333, 6.505, 11.4929166666667, 
    11.6275, 14.0754166666667, 16.5591666666667, 14.9191666666667, 
    14.0804166666667, 15.9579166666667, 13.21, 15.5595833333333, 
    16.3566666666667, 16.6279166666667, 14.2116666666667, 11.51625, 
    14.625, 14.7758333333333, 14.3008333333333, 13.3770833333333, 
    12.6420833333333, 9.81083333333333, 6.84875, 7.50125, 8.26791666666667, 
    11.1266666666667, 9.33958333333333, 5.27416666666667, 0.43625, 
    4.05916666666667, 0.0675, 4.48416666666667, 7.59791666666667, 
    7.93416666666667, 7.35416666666667, 8.72625, 7.64791666666667, 
    9.56041666666667, 10.08, 9.62041666666667, 9.22375, 7.78833333333333, 
    9.89583333333333, 8.34083333333333, 9.55833333333333, 5.55958333333333, 
    2.96541666666667, 0.897916666666667, -0.807916666666667, 
    -1.76875, -3.45458333333333, -2.23583333333333, -0.18875, 
    0.573333333333333, 0.973333333333333, 4.225, 2.7525, 1.99083333333333, 
    1.50666666666667, 1.10333333333333, 2.66291666666667, 4.52166666666667, 
    4.9075, 6.25583333333333, 8.1975, 5.69625, 5.81625, 8.01458333333333, 
    6.28416666666667, -0.420833333333333, -0.555416666666667, 
    -0.485416666666667, -0.599583333333333, -2.83291666666667, 
    -4.32, -4.20708333333333, -5.2775, -1.79333333333333, 0.420416666666667, 
    -3.52, 0.6125, 1.63625, 2.69125, 5.0475, 6.22791666666667, 
    2.54708333333333, -0.890833333333333, -2.08666666666667, 
    -0.840416666666667, -0.16, -2.14041666666667, -0.218333333333333, 
    2.30125), Variable_6 = c(6.92875, 2.515, 4.37041666666667, 
    2.26166666666667, 1.79333333333333, 2.47333333333333, 2.83083333333333, 
    2.94, 4.53416666666667, 3.08375, 1.74958333333333, 1.7175, 
    3.23583333333333, 2.25541666666667, 2.3375, 1.4575, 2.0375, 
    4.51791666666667, 3.0675, 3.39875, 3.21083333333333, 3.99458333333333, 
    4.24166666666667, 2.38, 2.07041666666667, 1.70458333333333, 
    1.11125, 1.29166666666667, 1.98625, 1.4075, 2.85625, 3.79541666666667, 
    1.93, 1.77916666666667, 2.61833333333333, 4.50291666666667, 
    2.97583333333333, 5.98458333333333, 3.7675, 2.06583333333333, 
    1.99541666666667, 1.03916666666667, 2.26, 3.59125, 2.59458333333333, 
    1.97583333333333, 1.91791666666667, 3.00791666666667, 3.80833333333333, 
    3.87333333333333, 3.2175, 2.4125, 3.37416666666667, 3.95291666666667, 
    3.09291666666667, 3.68875, 1.51541666666667, 2.40791666666667, 
    2.78041666666667, 1.59541666666667, 2.82, 3.93708333333333, 
    2.46708333333333, 2.76541666666667, 2.35208333333333, 2.27291666666667, 
    3.62875, 4.41291666666667, 1.90916666666667, 1.5575, 5.05625, 
    6.83375, 5.00166666666667, 3.66416666666667, 2.64333333333333, 
    5.42791666666667, 8.6, 11.1095833333333, 5.98791666666667, 
    2.21708333333333, 2.44041666666667, 2.63541666666667, 1.52666666666667, 
    3.31083333333333, 5.35375, 2.77666666666667, 4.72875, 3.55583333333333, 
    4.14875, 7.35666666666667, 7.70666666666667, 6.15333333333333, 
    5.0575, 0.9975, 1.85041666666667, 3.17291666666667, 1.88833333333333, 
    1.55583333333333, 2.57375, 1.48041666666667), Variable_7 = c(61.75, 
    63.6666666666667, 53.6666666666667, 55.25, 60.625, 58.375, 
    64.4166666666667, 68.0833333333333, 70.125, 61.0833333333333, 
    72.3333333333333, 74.625, 67.2916666666667, 56.5833333333333, 
    73.2916666666667, 76.9166666666667, 74.0833333333333, 70.4583333333333, 
    64.875, 62.75, 65.7916666666667, 62.125, 57.125, 59.5, 65.125, 
    70.7916666666667, 80, 79.7083333333333, 74.0833333333333, 
    65.375, 65.0833333333333, 68.7083333333333, 80.9166666666667, 
    73.1666666666667, 80.9166666666667, 74.0833333333333, 75.5416666666667, 
    65.9166666666667, 66.7916666666667, 75.0416666666667, 76.4166666666667, 
    80.1666666666667, 81.5416666666667, 76.375, 70.75, 69.25, 
    75.7916666666667, 75.75, 72.375, 72.4166666666667, 86.0416666666667, 
    73.5, 75.3333333333333, 78.1666666666667, 72.875, 67.7916666666667, 
    72.375, 76.2916666666667, 70.2083333333333, 66.2916666666667, 
    71.125, 76, 78.4166666666667, 79.4166666666667, 83.0833333333333, 
    82.4166666666667, 70.6666666666667, 55.7083333333333, 78.7916666666667, 
    73.5833333333333, 71.9166666666667, 76.2916666666667, 81.0416666666667, 
    72.3333333333333, 81.7083333333333, 73.125, 71.6666666666667, 
    79.3333333333333, 83.0833333333333, 80.5, 73.9166666666667, 
    76.2916666666667, 77.5416666666667, 71.125, 87.75, 83.375, 
    74.9583333333333, 78.4166666666667, 73.375, 70.2916666666667, 
    73.0416666666667, 80.4583333333333, 84.2083333333333, 86.5416666666667, 
    75.125, 60.4583333333333, 56.5, 80.6666666666667, 77.625, 
    81.4166666666667), Variable_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Variable_9 = c(4.55, 
    5.98333333333333, 11.4166666666667, 11.3166666666667, 11.3333333333333, 
    11.1333333333333, 9.96666666666667, 8.58333333333333, 1.45, 
    4, 1.1, 9.73333333333333, 10.3333333333333, 6.5, 3.31666666666667, 
    7.05, 10.05, 9.95, 6.43333333333333, 10.7333333333333, 11.1, 
    11.0333333333333, 10.75, 9.13333333333333, 9.98333333333333, 
    8.48333333333333, 6.56666666666667, 8.51666666666667, 7.63333333333333, 
    10.5166666666667, 5.81666666666667, 5.05, 6.48333333333333, 
    5.23333333333333, 0, 0, 1.45, 1.18333333333333, 2.25, 3.56666666666667, 
    0.3, 5.75, 5.73333333333333, 5.45, 7.05, 7.41666666666667, 
    5.71666666666667, 5.31666666666667, 2.93333333333333, 6.8, 
    5.48333333333333, 0.516666666666667, 8.58333333333333, 8.73333333333333, 
    9.35, 7.05, 9.13333333333333, 1.76666666666667, 9.01666666666667, 
    6.58333333333333, 9.11666666666667, 2.18333333333333, 4.36666666666667, 
    2.56666666666667, 0, 0.216666666666667, 0.766666666666667, 
    1.66666666666667, 0, 4.11666666666667, 0.483333333333333, 
    1.35, 0.45, 2.53333333333333, 2.01666666666667, 4.4, 0.75, 
    1.4, 2.96666666666667, 4.18333333333333, 8.56666666666667, 
    7.7, 1.8, 8.51666666666667, 3.2, 0.05, 8.45, 0, 0.883333333333333, 
    0, 0.383333333333333, 0, 1.83333333333333, 4.9, 8.36666666666667, 
    5.78333333333333, 3.31666666666667, 5.4, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.4), Variable_10 = c(1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.3, 0.225, 
    0, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.975, 1.5, 0, 0.925, 0, 0.425, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.675, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.4, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.475, 0.425, 0, 0.225, 0.375, 0, 0, 1.175, 0, 
    0.85, 0.7, 0.375, 0, 1.55, 0.1, 0, 0.475, 0.35, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.175, 1.675, 0.075, 0, 3.325, 0, 0.8, 0.125, 0, 1.35, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Variable_11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Variable_12 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), Variable_13 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey Samuel, can you provide sample data? Here's the FAQ for producing a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Questions should be self contained. Do not link to the data since that can become stale later.  See top of [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: @Rmematey is that edit in the Question good enogh?

Comment: The {slider} package is probably your R solution: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slider/vignettes/rowwise.html

Comment: Can you add the model you'd fit for the `1:77`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Model:
model_A<-lm(formula=Produkt_A~weekday+Variable_1+Variable_2+Variable_3+Variable_4+Variable_5+Variable_6+Variable_7+Variable_8+Variable_9+Variable_10+Variable_11+Variable_12+Variable_13,data=df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the desired output

```r
formula <- as.formula(paste0("Produkt_A ~ weekday + ", paste0("Variable_", 1:13, collapse="+")) )
lapply(77:(nrow(data)-7), function(x){
    cof <- coef(fit<-lm(formula, data=data[1:77 + (x-77),]))
    if(any(is.na(cof))) fit <- lm(paste0("Produkt_",l," ~ ", paste0(names(cof)[!is.na(cof)][-1], collapse="+")), data=data[1:77 + (x-77),])
    predict(fit, data[1:7+x, ]) 
})
```

#### output

```r
[[1]]
      78       79       80       81       82       83       84 
175.6231 187.2455 172.6803 198.4860 196.4347 182.1002 176.8268 

[[2]]
      79       80       81       82       83       84       85 
190.0454 177.9412 198.1522 195.6015 179.8084 172.5813 162.7283 

[[3]]
      80       81       82       83       84       85       86 
180.2934 199.5343 197.2900 179.7369 173.6123 164.2395 197.3890
```

If you want to step by a week then change `77:(nrow(data)-7)` to `seq(77,nrow(data)-7, 7)`

#### output

```r
[[1]]
      78       79       80       81       82       83       84 
175.6231 187.2455 172.6803 198.4860 196.4347 182.1002 176.8268 

[[2]]
      85       86       87       88       89       90       91 
165.3612 202.1819 202.9133 192.1088 196.2086 190.3211 192.5323 

[[3]]
      92       93       94       95       96       97       98 
190.0432 234.1672 240.5036 221.9270 199.6451 206.9269 225.3737
```

Also I think that you want to `apply` the same code to all the products if so, the following code will give a named list where each element contains the predictions for that product:

```r
sapply(LETTERS[1:6], function(l){
  formula <- as.formula(paste0("Produkt_",l,  " ~ weekday + ", paste0("Variable_", 1:13, collapse="+")) )
  unlist(lapply(seq(77,nrow(data)-7, 7), function(x){
    cof <- coef(fit<-lm(formula, data=data[1:77 + (x-77),]))
    if(any(is.na(cof))) fit <- lm(paste0("Produkt_",l," ~ weekday + ", paste0(names(cof)[!is.na(cof)][-1], collapse="+")), data=data[1:77 + (x-77),])
    predict(fit, data[1:7+x, ]) 
  }), use.names=F)
}) -> l
as.data.frame(l) -> l
names(l) <- paste0("Produkt_",LETTERS[1:6][-2])
```

Output

```
   Produkt_A Produkt_B Produkt_C Produkt_D Produkt_E Produkt_F
1   183.1617  255.8523  34.78719  9.040423  19.85345  72.48134
2   179.0516  236.6205  33.66128 14.456406  15.23111  52.14860
3   169.4564  233.5267  36.56796 11.893548  18.04682  47.84604
4   195.5562  237.8086  39.53323 12.611249  18.62263  57.85943
5   195.7860  244.9322  42.66896 10.579288  20.81832  64.33085
6   185.1508  244.6651  44.30452 11.109312  21.15966  66.57021
7   180.0834  238.5539  42.82646  9.011723  23.64313  68.25384
8   172.3084  236.5883  33.38472  6.052889  23.20801  60.28078
9   199.3014  251.1623  35.95758 17.642626  15.75082  49.16527
10  199.2620  244.1736  36.81896 20.277373  15.65039  57.63127
11  185.4162  232.4378  33.42248  9.914847  14.76501  58.14915
12  198.1636  250.0573  38.33021 17.008143  17.60963  53.38972
13  192.1136  217.5651  30.07103 13.590327  18.93781  57.78008
14  196.7885  222.4964  31.21988 16.192406  23.95876  55.00223
15  195.3891  229.2507  31.85575 17.436000  29.62023  51.42169
16  231.2512  236.6823  29.52290 22.564247  21.73221  49.89134
17  238.8464  254.4130  31.74025 23.147904  27.33184  53.82207
18  220.2332  240.9582  32.17718 22.994808  24.63406  56.82193
19  200.0848  230.6290  33.54214 21.710842  20.59998  54.37489
20  209.8458  245.5775  38.18210 22.251512  22.91061  55.50162
21  229.8341  259.3681  37.87675 20.772142  29.79006  65.34059
```

Comment: thanks for the fast help, i try both of your codes and get this warning:50: In predict.lm(lm(formula, data = data[1:77 + (x - 77),  ... :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Comment: and istead of saving the new data in a list, is it possible to save it in a data.frame

Comment: the warning message was rising from having `NA` coefficient I corrected for that, for making it into a data.frame, you can change the first `lapply` by `sapply` and put the second `lapply` inside an `unlist` call, then convert the resulting matrix to a data.frame, by `as.data.frame`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @SamuelLehmann accept the answer so future users will find the solution easily